# Impurity or Randomness in Haskell's profiling

Tags: performance, haskell, profiling, cabal

I'm implementing [RayTracingInOneWeekend](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html) and I optimized it from `33m` to `23s` for image size `384x216` scene and the parameters as given in [the article](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html). However, when I profile it, the `entries` (the 5th column from the left in the screenshot below) changes on almost every run. How is that possible? In my program everything stays *same*, including even the random number generators, as generators are created as (you can see it on [github](https://github.com/snawaz/ray-tracers/blob/master/src/Image.hs#L75)):

```hs
g = mkStdGen (i * width + j)
```

If `width` and `height` stay same, then all `g` (one for each pixel) should stay same as well. However, as you can see the two screenshots have different values in the `entries` column.

[image]

[image]

What could be the reason behind this impurity? Or the profiler is *not* just able to gather all the information and the numbers are *not* exact (means, in reality the frequency of function calls are different from the numbers shown above; the [docs](http://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#json-profile-format) however does not say anything like that).

My program builds with `cabal v2-build -O2 --enable-profiling  --enable-executable-profiling` and I dont pass `-prof -fprof-auto` to `ghc-options` (I guess `cabal` takes care of that). I've also used [`-threaded` and `parallel` library](https://github.com/snawaz/ray-tracers/blob/master/ray-tracers.cabal#L38).

I'm on GHC 8.6.5 and Cabal 3.2.

Comment: Do you expect your CPU to run the same program in exactly the same way every time?  CPUs change behavior constantly -- for example, in response to their temperature.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Why would the CPU performance affect the number of times 
 functions has been called, especially if the input has not changed? If my program calls a function `N` number of times, it should be `N` irrespective of CPU's temperature.

Comment: Most profilers only take a statistical sample of calls, as opposed to measuring all calls.  That would cause timing to matter.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. If you're sure about it, in this case too, then please post an answer and elaborating it. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, the profiler in multi-core mode does not run consistently — not sure if that counts as *bug*. I ran the program couple of times without passing `-N` to `RTS` and now every time I see the same `entries` count:

[image]

Not sure if that *proves* that my program does not have any *impurity*. I'm stil looking for better and more plausible response (if there is any, at all).